# HaProxy TCP Subdomains

Tags: proxy, haproxy, gameserver

```
global
        log         127.0.0.1 local2
        chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
        pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
        maxconn     4500
        user        haproxy
        group       haproxy
        daemon
defaults
        mode                    tcp
        log                     global
        retries                 8
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout server 10s
        timeout client 10s

frontend 0
    bind *:25565
        mode tcp
        acl test hdr(host) -i test.mydomain.com
        use_backend 0 if test
backend 0
    mode tcp
        server node0 22.28.29.28:25585 check
```

Hello,

I'm trying to use haproxy for my Minecraft server. What I want is a config that I can just add more subdomains and what IPs they proxy to. The issue I'm having is when you try to connect it just says "`Logging in...`" than says "`Disconnected`". Am I doing anything wrong?

I also have `*.mydomain.com` pointing to my haproxy server.

Thanks :)

Comment: The answer from @chicks is 100% correct... *unless* you are feeling extremely clever and aren't afraid to do some work.  The minecraft client/server protocol appears to be "client talks first" and the server name seems to be sent in-band... so it *should* be possible to configure HAProxy to inspect the bytes in the payload of that first packet and select the back-end accordingly... but this is a fairly advanced undertaking, as you have to identify exactly which bytes mean what, and configure HAProxy at a very low "close to the wire" level.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `mode minecraft` as a patch for haproxy would be epic.

Comment: lol @chicks.  Actually, it may not be too tricky if we go for a fairly lazy approach based on what I have found of protocol docs... If I could get someone with a minecraft server to try this in the frontend block: `tcp-request inspect-delay 5s` and `use-backend my_backend_name if { req.payload(0,0),lower -m sub thesubdomain.example.com }` "my_backend_name" would be the name of the back-end, which is "0" in this question.  The `use_backend` line would be repeated for each possible matching hostname/back-end combo.

Answer (score 2):

Any header-based functionality won't work for minecraft since TCP-mode doesn't look for any headers.  [Hosting multiple minecraft servers](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/how-to-have-multiple-servers-on-one-ip/) is usually done by using unique ports.  The other easy choice is multiple IP's.  If you want to go with multiple ports then you would need to create a `frontend` for each listening port in haproxy.

Answer (score 1):

Your ACL is never going to match in `mode tcp`, since you're checking a layer7 functionality.

Change both occurrences of `mode` to http and you should be good.

Comment: but [minecraft connections are not http](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Port_forwarding) so that won't work

Comment: Well, that's a whole other story then and your answer is much more fitting.